# BIRT Report not running in eclipse after update to windows 8.1

Tags: java, eclipse, birt, windows-8.1

I am not able to run the birt reports in eclipse after updating to windows 8.1 recently. Eclipse layout view works fine but when I run the report nothing happens. Below is the information I have when I  debug report. Please suggest a way to fix this issue

```
Oct 19, 2013 5:09:02 AM org.eclipse.birt.report.debug.internal.core.vm.ReportVMServer start
INFO: [Server] client accepted
Oct 19, 2013 5:09:02 AM org.eclipse.birt.report.debug.internal.core.vm.ReportVMServer$1 run
INFO: [Server] enter request dispatching
Oct 19, 2013 5:09:02 AM org.eclipse.birt.report.debug.internal.core.launcher.ReportLauncher configEngine
INFO: User class path received: 
Oct 19, 2013 5:09:03 AM org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.EngineTask handleFatalExceptions
SEVERE: An error happened while running the report. Cause:
org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: Failed to initialize emitter.
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.EmitterUtil.getOuputStream(EmitterUtil.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.html.HTMLReportEmitter.initialize(HTMLReportEmitter.java:356)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.EngineTask.initializeContentEmitter(EngineTask.java:2286)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.doRun(RunAndRenderTask.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.run(RunAndRenderTask.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.debug.internal.core.launcher.ReportLauncher.createReport(ReportLauncher.java:600)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.debug.internal.core.launcher.ReportLauncher.renderReport(ReportLauncher.java:547)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.debug.internal.core.launcher.ReportLauncher.run(ReportLauncher.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.debug.internal.core.launcher.ReportLauncher.main(ReportLauncher.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.debug.internal.core.ReportDebugger.start(ReportDebugger.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: \new_report.rptdesign.html (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:212)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.EmitterUtil.getOuputStream(EmitterUtil.java:77)
    ... 22 more

Oct 19, 2013 5:09:03 AM org.eclipse.birt.report.debug.internal.core.launcher.ReportLauncher renderReport
SEVERE: Engine exception
org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: Failed to initialize emitter.
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.EmitterUtil.getOuputStream(EmitterUtil.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.html.HTMLReportEmitter.initialize(HTMLReportEmitter.java:356)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.EngineTask.initializeContentEmitter(EngineTask.java:2286)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.doRun(RunAndRenderTask.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.run(RunAndRenderTask.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.debug.internal.core.launcher.ReportLauncher.createReport(ReportLauncher.java:600)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.debug.internal.core.launcher.ReportLauncher.renderReport(ReportLauncher.java:547)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.debug.internal.core.launcher.ReportLauncher.run(ReportLauncher.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.debug.internal.core.launcher.ReportLauncher.main(ReportLauncher.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.debug.internal.core.ReportDebugger.start(ReportDebugger.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: \new_report.rptdesign.html (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:212)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.EmitterUtil.getOuputStream(EmitterUtil.java:77)
    ... 22 more

Oct 19, 2013 5:09:03 AM org.eclipse.birt.report.debug.internal.core.vm.ReportVMServer$1 run
WARNING: [Server] client disconnected
```

Comment: Also posted at http://www.birt-exchange.org/forum/index.php?/topic/30482-birt-report-not-running-in-eclipse-after-update-to-windows-81/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is a registry entry, if the local user made a update to Win 7 SP1.

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeaturControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION

jawaw.exe=9000

If this entry is set, then the internal web browser always start IE in compatibility mode Version 9 no matter what parameters you use, to start Eclipse or your .jnlp application.

So you have to delete this registry entry or you set it to 9999. 9999 means that the IE Browser don´t run in compatibility mode.

You also could use the following entry to start your application:

```
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=ie
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion=9999
```

at the end of elipse.ini

With this settings problems with IE11 were disappeared

See [eclipse tracker](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=422056)

Comment: +1 Tried several other workarounds, but this is the only one that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

BBC News is [reporting issues](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/technology-24608277) with windows 8.1.  suggest you revert to an early version to run BIRT.

The link in [comments](http://www.birt-exchange.org/forum/index.php?/topic/30482-birt-report-not-running-in-eclipse-after-update-to-windows-81/) indicates there are multiple parties with BIRT and Windows 8.1 issues.  Some reports of not being able to uninstall 8.1. There is a video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WkS-PuXxxm0 that may help with the un-install.

**Edit November 15, 2013**
Per http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php?/topic/30484-birt-report-not-running-in-eclipse-after-update-to-windows-81/ users seem to only be having this issue when trying to preview the report in BIRT, opening the report in a web window seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a blank page and when parameters were involved, the parameter window didn't load up.

I think I've found a way around it, though it doesn't work in preview mode:

In report designer go to Window>Preferences>Report Design>Preview and set "always use external browsers" to true. Click Apply.

While still in the preferences tab, go to General>Web Browser and select "Use external web browser" and select the browser you would like to test on.

This has enabled me to continue development on windows 8, though it is not ideal!

I hope this helps!